# Why were there civilians in Char?

Tags: starcraft-2

So I was cheerfully slaughtering Terrans at Char, specifically here:

[image: Cropped screenshot showing the minimap of the Old Soldiers mission from Heart of the Swarm; a location is circled that is east of the initial Zerg base and south of Warfield's Tactical Operations Center]

Warfield eventually screams something along the lines of: *"evacuate the civilians!"*

As he finishes that sentence, I begin laughing as I hunt for civilians......... wait. What. Civilians? In ***Char***?

At first I thought *"maybe he means the scientists"* buuuut, as far as I am concerned, I destroyed both research facilities (there used to be two in both sides of the map), and I really doubt there would be scientists outside them. As you can appreciate in the image above, I am located in an area with no such facilities - and that's precisely when Warfield screams. Moreover, both facilities were destroyed by then so... yeah.

Civilians. Why were there civilians in an abominable place like Char? I mean, it has been like three weeks since they claimed the planet. Which was full with Zerg. Everywhere.

Comment: This was too funny. `as I hunt for civilians......... wait. What. Civilians? In Char?` +1

Comment: As funny as it may be, this doesn't sound like a real question.

Comment: @Bora: Why? I was just wondering about SC's plot (sending civilians to a very hostile planet). I assumed it would be fine since I made other plot questions about Final Fantasy before.

Comment: Civilians are a base term for non-military.  Plus someone has to run around with bug spray!

Comment: @Omega This question has been closed, but I and currently two other users have voted to reopen it. I believe you can cast a reopen vote too. If this doesn't get reopened after a day or two, and you would like it to be reopened, you could raise this issue at [meta].

Comment: As to why I voted to reopen, I believe it's a game plot/lore question, which is allowed as per the [FAQ]: "*What kind of questions can I ask here?… If your question generally covers things such as… Plot and characters in games… then you are in the right place to ask your question!*"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The term civilians includes not just scientists but also medical staff, maintenance workers, construction workers (the fortress ain't gonna build itself), some bureaucrats that make sure the marines get paid their share of minerals and food, cleaning staff to wash the ashes off the buildings for when the general makes his inspection and of course mario, the plumber.

A fortress can't live on marines alone.

Comment: It was at this moment I though to myself *"well, SCVs don't fight"*, but  I discarded that idea given the massive drill they got. I mean, if they can break mineral clusters, they should be able to split a zealot's skull.

Answer (score 8):

Are you familiar with that scene in Clerks where they're discussing the rebels blowing up the second Death Star?

> **Randal:** A construction job of that magnitude would require a helluva lot more manpower than the Imperial army had to offer. I'll bet there were independent contractors working on that thing: plumbers, aluminum siders, roofers.
>
> **Dante:** Not just Imperials, is what you're getting at.
>
> **Randal:** Exactly. In order to get it built quickly and quietly they'd hire anybody who could do the job. Do you think the average storm trooper knows how to install a toilet main? All they know is killing and white uniforms.

So basically you're killing innocent plumbers and roofers.  But it's alright, they knew the risks involved, so it's their own fault you killed them.

Comment: Lucas actually added something in the prequels to [absolve the rebels of any guilt for blowing up the second Death Star](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cFKhV_X6-cg&feature=youtu.be&t=50s). Yup no longer living beings but just a bunch of robots. #hanshotfirst

Comment: +1 for Clerks quote :D